# Best deinterlacing filter for FFMPEG (no GPU)

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

I am hoping you can help. I am trying to extract frames (1 per second) from various videos and from various sources. However, I am getting blur/deinterlacing (see below). I've tried with various types of footage and eventually downloaded some F1 highlights to demo to you the type of output I am getting.

I am using the following command and below are 4 example frames. Does anyone have any advice on changes we could make to clean up the images extracted and sharpen them?

> ffmpeg -ss 960 -t 100 -i "video.mp4" -qscale:v 2 -vf yadif=1:0:0 -r 1 "%06d.jpg"

also tried

> ffmpeg -ss 960 -t 100 -i "video.mp4" -qscale:v 2 -vf yadif=1:***-1***:0 -r 1 "%06d.jpg"

**Examples**

[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]
[image: Example3]
[image: Example4]

Comment: What's your source video? Progressive shouldn't do that, interlaced likely could. I can't get Sky F1 to screen cap or download, DRM. Have you tried a manual frame save from VLC for comparison? [Not that I know anything about ffmpeg, tbh ;)

Comment: This was only a sample demo that was particularly affected. The source is highly variable. I haven’t tried VLC as the project is designed to be automated and installing VLC isn’t a option.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I can't really say on ffmpeg as I tend to use Handbrake for anything like this, which saves my rather coding-limited brain ;)  GUI, point & click, save as preset & set to batch mode once happy. I've never tried batching stills though. I tend to only need the occasional manual still, usually just in VLC for convenience.